# Equalizing the array elements

Tags: vector

If you have `three or more numbers` and a division parameter such that you have to equalizing the arrays elements in minimum number of operations. You can equalize the elements by dividing the array elements from division parameter only.

Example 1 :
Vector arr{64,32,16};
Division parameter=2.
Minimum no. Of operations are 3.

Explanation: divide 64 by 2 two times and divide 32 by 2 one times. So min operations are 2+1=3.

Example 2:
Vector arr{64,33,25};
Division parameter=2.
Minimum no. Of operations are 15.

Explanation:
For minimum no. Of operations you have to divide 64 (six times) ,33(5 times) , 25 (4 times) . Such that both of three elements become 1 .

**division parameter is user given. Vector array and its size is also user given**

**There is always integral division ex: 33/2=16.**

Please help me to solve this query in an efficient way.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your attempt if you want suggestions for making it efficient.

Comment: I tried a lot. I didn't find any efficient way. Always there a brute force method to solve any query .In this question, if we check each and every element with each other elements then it is possible but through this hard code complexity tends to very large value for some inputs.

Comment: Select _one_ language and post the code with what you tried for that language.

Comment: Okay i fixed it

Comment: Do you want a c++14 solution specifically? Just tag with c++ otherwise. More importantly, you have still not shown your attempt.

Comment: Yes i want c++14  solution. i am unable to complete my code as i don't know the way to solve this query. I hope you have a good way to solve this problem

Comment: It sounds like you need a code writing service then. That's now how SO works, we're not just going to write a solution for you.

Comment: I am not demanding any code service. I just need a way to solve. Don't take me wrong sir.

Comment: No worries, I'm just trying to understand what you're looking for. You say you want a c++ solution, but also you don't want any code? I'm a little confused about what you want.

Comment: Sorry for that . I fixed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking GCD was my first thought until you corrected the question to clarify that division is integer division.

Now, I came up with 2 algorithms

## Algorithm 1:

1. Take largest number, divide it till it becomes 2nd largest, or equal to the 2nd largest, and increase the counter with each division
2. If it becomes second largest, repeat the above steps again.
3. If it becomes equal to the 2nd largest, then then start comparing it with the 3rd largest, but now, increase the counter by 2 with each division of it (as there are 2 equal largest numbers), and then repeat the above steps.

Ex -

```
[64,32,17,36], div factor = 2, counter(ctr) = 0
64 -> 32, [32,32,17,36] steps = 1, ctr = 1
36 -> 18, [32,32,17,18] steps = 1, ctr = 2
32 -> 16, [16,16,17,18] steps = 1*2(as 2 values = 32) = 2, ctr = 4
18 -> 9, [16,16,17,9] steps = 1, ctr = 5
17 -> 8, [16,16,8,9] steps = 1, ctr = 6
16 -> 8, [8,8,8,9] steps = 1*2(as 2 values = 16) = 2, ctr = 8
9 -> 4, [8,8,8,4] steps = 1, ctr = 9
8 -> 4, [4,4,4,4] steps = 1*3(as 3 values = 8) = 3, ctr = 12
```

So the minimum steps come out to be 12.
(64 -> 4, 32 -> 3, 17 -> 2, 36 -> 3) = 4 + 3 + 2 +3 = 12

## Algorithm 2 (Better)

1. Start by equalizing pairs, moving left from right.
2. With each division of the left number, increase the
   counter by the index of right number (or index of left
   number + 1)
3. With each division of right number, increase the counter
   by 1
4. Continue till you reach the last pairs.

Ex -

```
[64,32,17,36], div factor 2, counter (ctr) = 0
(64,32),17,36 -> (32,32),17,36 => steps = 1*1 = 1, ctr = 1
32,(32,17),36 -> 8,(8,8),36 => steps = 2*2 + 1 = 5, ctr = 6
8,8,(8,36) -> 8,8,(4,4) => steps = 1*3 + 3 = 6, ctr = 12
```

Ans = 12